# I'd like to rename a tag due to rebranding

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

I created the tag [pachube](/questions/tagged/pachube) on Stack Overflow but would like to rename it to [cosm](/questions/tagged/cosm) as we have rebranded our api as such.

[Here's an article about the rebrand](http://blog.cosm.com/2012/05/pachube-is-now-cosm.html)

I'm not sure if tag synonyms are exactly the thing I am looking for as adding [cosm](/questions/tagged/cosm) as a synonym seems like it would point to the master tag [pachube](/questions/tagged/pachube) which is the wrong way around?

Excuse me if I am missing something obvious!

**NOTE:** I have not created the [cosm](/questions/tagged/cosm) tag yet.

Comment: Can't you just retag them? I only see two under the original name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The few questions have been retagged to [cosm](/questions/tagged/cosm) and the tag wiki and excerpt should appear there shortly. Since there are only a few questions, it's not currently possible for normal users to create a tag synonym to the old name, so a moderator would have to do that. However, I'm not sure it's necessary since it wasn't a huge topic before the name change and I doubt anyone would become confused by it.

Comment: I should have just created the [tag:cosm] tag and retagged them myself. I really appreciate the help and sorry for the hassle!